# Saving data to multiple tables in php and sql

Tags: php, sql

Good day! Can somebody tell me what's wrong to my code for me save data into 3 tables.

Sales table:

```
srfno
clientid
datecreated
returnreason
explanation
```

Sales_item table:

```
itemid
srfno
qty
serial
desc
```

Client table:

```
clientid
clientname
address
contactno
```

I have 1 PHP form were data should be saved in these 3 tables. Now, the only thing I can't figure out is how to save qty, sn and desc to sales_item table and the rest are now saving.

Here's my code for saving to sales_item:

```
$return="Select * from `sales_item`";   
        $result1=mysql_query($return,$con); 
        $retid=mysql_num_rows($result1);
        $retid=$retid+1;
        $addret="Insert into `sales_item` (`sitemid`, `srfno`, `retqty`, `retdesc`,`retserial`, `exqty`, `exdesc`,`exserial`,)
     VALUES ('2 ','$srfno', '$qty', '$desc', '$serialno', ' ', ' ', ' ') ";
        $return=mysql_query($addret);
```

Here's my running code for saving clientname etc. to client table:

```
$clientquery = "Select `clientid` from client where `name`= '$clientname' ";
    $result=mysql_query($clientquery,$con);
    $cli = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($cli==1)
    {
        while($client= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                if(isset($client['clientid']))
                {
                $clientid= $client['clientid'];

                }
            }
    }
    else
    { 
        if($cli==0)
        {
        $client="Select * from `client`";   
        $result=mysql_query($client,$con);  
        $clientid=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $clientid=$clientid+1;
        $addclient="Insert into `client` (`clientid`,`name`,`address`,`email`,`contactperson`,`contactno`)
        VALUES ('$clientid','$clientname','$clientadd','NULL','$contactperson','$cellphoneno')";
        $client=mysql_query($addclient);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query (for saving to sales_item), you should remove the last comma in field list:

```
... `exserial`,) ....
```

In the second query, if you want a NULL value, you should set it without '' (although this would not imply a SQL error):

```
... 'NULL' --> NULL
```

Comment: @Ipg but still i can't get the value of srfno from sales_table that i need for srfno in sales_item table

Comment: THANKS man! i thought it's a very complicated error.